# Approach to mail sending solution on OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift

I am trying to build a mail sending solution, weekly e-mail reminders for colleagues and I'm trying to do so by using OpenShift.
So far, I've made a Python script that initializes connection to our corporate SMTP server and sends out a test message.

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com', 25)
print(s.help())
print(s.helo())
print(s.mail("my.email@company.com"))
print(s.rcpt("my.email@company.com"))
s.data("From: my.email@company.com\r\nTo: my.email@company.com\r\n\r\nTest message from SMTP server\r\n.\r\n.")
print(s.quit())
```

OpenShift then fetches this code from Git repository and creates a build which then creates a pod.
The problem becomes apparent when the pod crashes with status *"Crash Loop Back-Off"* making the code run again in a loop, indefinitely.

My question is whether OpenShift is even intended to run these one-time jobs that are triggered externally, for example by Airflow. Or is there a specific way to make the pod run only once it's triggered and not run again after command execution?
I have tried setting ***RestartPolicy*** in a pod,  build and deployment, but I either get an error message saying that *restartPolicy:**Never*** is not a supported value, or that the parameter cannot be changed.

Please help me out with approaching this task. Thank you.

Comment: One-time jobs is _exactly_ the use case for Jobs (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/nodes/jobs/nodes-nodes-jobs.html)